# Are Particles Necessary?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, elementary-particles

I started my reasoning from a curved spacetime: in the description of General Relativity, the universe is a continuum and we get to the Einstein Field Equations.

Space and time may or not be continuous and can be flat, but I think we need particles in it in order to have an universe with *physical* sense. We cannot just have empty curved spacetime. This doesn't mean no *mathematical* sense, but General Relativity can describe only gravity and electromagnetism (which, to be precise, is unified in Quantum Electrodynamics with the weak interaction and not with gravity).

But *we need an interaction like the strong interaction* (*we need something that glues thing together*), which that is contemplated in General Relativity because it's not a part of (and not a consequence) of the Einstein Field Equations.

Or am I wrong?

Comment: I see no reason you can't just set $T_{\mu\nu}=0$ throughout a hypothetical universe.

Comment: it has a mathematical sense, but physical?

Comment: Quarks and general relativity don't really get along: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LU6kbao3vo

Comment: @Anto: an electrovac solution of GR has a lot of physically reasonable applications.  I'd argue that the Kerr solution for describing a black hole far from any matter is probably the best-modeled macroscopic object that exists, in terms of correspondence of a mathematical model and expected physical behaviour.

Comment: This is true but the question focuses about the importance of  the strong interaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General Relativity does not describe all phenomena. It's concern is to describe gravitational effects and those only. The Einstein Field Equations determine how spacetime will curve on the presence of matter and, as a consequence, tells matter how to move. In principle it does not describe Electromagnetism.

Nevertheless, it is possible to formulate Electromagnetism in curved spacetime, which is what we sometimes refer to as "Einstein--Maxwell theory". This is frequently treated in General Relativity books (see Wald's Chapter 4, for example), so I won't dive deep into it here. Notice this corresponds essentially to choosing a specific matter content, which in this case is just the electromagnetic fields (and possibly the source charges). You pick a particular stress-energy tensor (i.e., a particular sort of matter) and solve the Einstein Equations for it. This sort of procedure allows, for example, to study charged black holes (see Wald's Chapter 6, Problem 3).

On the other hand, let us think about the non-gravitational interactions. GR deals really well with gravity, but we still know the Universe has electromagnetic, strong, and weak interactions. As I mentioned, we can incorporate Classical Electromagnetism within GR, but we also know things should behave according to the laws of Quantum Mechanics. We know how to describe the non-gravitational interactions in accordance with QM: we use a framework known as Quantum Field Theory (QFT). The quantum field theory describing Electromagnetism in the quantum level is what we call Quantum Electrodynamics, and it *does not* incorporate the weak interaction in its description. However, nowadays we also know how to describe weak and strong interactions by similar means and we have a quantum field theory that describes all the known non-gravitational interactions: it is known as the Standard Model of Particle Physics, or just Standard Model.

The Standard Model is a theory in flat spacetime. It knows nothing about gravity, but describes the remaining interactions with astonishing precision.

Hence, we have

1. one theory that describes gravitation incredibly well, but is classical, i.e., it does not incorporate quantum mechanics in its framework. Nevertheless, it also can be used together with Classical Electromagnetism to describe gravitational and electromagnetic phenomena at a classical level;
2. another theory that describes the non-gravitational interactions incredibly well and at the quantum level, but that does not work well with gravity.

Joining both descriptions is not particularly easy, and is certainly one of the greatest open problems in Physics. Gravity has peculiar features that make its quantized version stop making sense at very high energies (more specifically, it is non-renormalizable). Nevertheless, one can still consider Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetime (QFTCS) or Semiclassical Gravity, which essentially consist in keeping the spacetime background classical, but allow for the matter content to be quantum. QFTCS assumes the fields do not change the background, while a semiclassical description allows this backreaction so the Einstein Field Equations would become something like
$$G_{ab} = 8\pi \langle T_{ab}\rangle,$$
known as the Semiclassical Einstein Field Equations. $\langle T_{ab}\rangle$ is the expectation value of the stress-energy tensor on whatever state the quantum fields (which, for the Standard Model, describe strong, weak and electromagnetic interactions, as well as all usual matter we know and love) happen to be.

Of course, making computations in these frameworks is not something particularly simple (and I'm not even sure if we already know how to work with the Standard Model in curved spacetime, though we certainly can consider simpler theories), but yes, a complete description of our universe would need to consider not only GR, but also the non-gravitational interactions known from Particle Physics.

I should also mention that in most cases of interest we won't want to consider all the details that compose the Universe at once. For example, if you're studying a black hole, there might be no reason to consider strong interactions based on the fact that they wouldn't have much influence on your results, but would have much influence on how difficult your calculations get. An essential part of doing Physics is to able to neglect contributions that won't change our results up to our desired precision. For example, you certainly won't need to consider relativistic effects when building a house, since the gravitational field involved is pretty small and the Newtonian limit works just fine to the desired precision. In the same way, many applications of GR can neglect the other interactions because their effects would be negligible. This makes physical sense because Physics is an experimental science, i.e., it is interested in things that can be measured, and if you measurement equipment is not sensible enough to notice those contributions, there is no problem with neglecting them.

Finally, QFTCS doesn't really work that well with the notion of "particle", because it is observer-dependent. This is more subtle and I don't think it is that related to the question, so I won't emphasize much, but the things that really matter are the fields, and the notion of "particle" can be recovered in a few cases. You still have electrons, gluons, and so on, but they are abstract fields rather than the tiny balls we like to picture.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I understand what did you say: it's true that we don't need the strong interaction description in describing macroscopical (giant) things like black holes ; but the universe is made of all things that comes togheter and we need observers for this  universe to have a physical sense or otherwise is just math, I think we need something that glues and gives a shape to things, we need particles interactions, strong interaction. In this kind of reasoning I need  help

Comment: @Anto we do, but GR is not concerned with how to describe that. We simply assume things are kept together somehow and model their stress-energy tensor to compute gravitational stuff. Deep down, we know from the Standard Model that the reason things can exist is related to the strong interactions, electromagnetism and so on, but GR usually will take it for granted. It still makes physical sense because it is keeping the relevant parts of the problem, without having to pay attention to all the details at once.